# React Native - ListView, CloneWithRow with object not array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am pulling some data from a webservice.
On the calls that are returning JSON arrays i am able to do the following just fine.

```
 WebServiceHandler.get('http:/api.local/stock',{},{)
         .then((val)=>{
           this.setState({
             dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(val)
           })
         })
         .catch((error) => console.log('callapi:'+ JSON.stringify(error)));
  }
```

For instance the following data would work perfectly..

```
[
    "SKU1",
    "SKU2",
    "SKU3"
]
```

However when i try to feed object with keys like below it doesn't like it.

```
{
    "SKU1": {"level":11, "description":"This is SKU 1"},
    "SKU2": {"level":22, "description":"This is SKU 2"},
    "SKU3": {"level":33, "description":"This is SKU 3"}
}
```

Can ListView handle object with keys or do i need to loop and amend this data on receipt before I can pass it to ListView?

If i have to amend it, without looping it, does any framework offer a quick way to achieve this?

Comment: You can convert the object to an array with the key included in the item using spread operator. Something like that `functionObject.keys(response).map((key) => ({key, ...response[key]}))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not give object to cloneWithRows. you can convert to array or you can use cloneWithRowsAndSections. It accepts object and you can render sectionHeader aswell.

Check documentation -> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listviewdatasource.html

Comment: Perfect, just what i was looking for, just using the section so i can access the properties rather than pushing them all out. Works a treat!